# 03 yukon electrical

Tags: electrical, alternator, ignition, gmc, no-crank-no-start

Its an 03 yukon with a brand new battery in it. In the past 3 months it has went in for a no crank no start issue twice . Both times it was just an ignition fuse. Something is causing this fuse to be blown again and again and im not sure what it is. The car is taking extra power with my 1100 watt amp for my 2 12’ subwoofers. After it just came back from the shop for the fuse yesterday it wouldnt start  again today, but the dash lights and gauges  come on as they normally would and it clicks when i try to turn it, leading me to believe it isnt the ignition fuse this time. Im pretty sure its a bad alternator from this but not entirely sure. Im looking to find a way to prevent the same ignition fuse from blowing a 3rd time. I also tried to jump start it which gave enough power to the battery to put my lights and gauges back on but then it just clicks and shortly after that it loses all power.

Comment: Please don't delete your valid questions. I undeleted it and am hoping you'd post your own answer as an answer. Appreciate you asking this separate question here.

Comment: Are you aware that alternators output low current at idle rpm? Using your amp on medium to high settings at idle will pull more current from the battery than the alternator can recharge it. Best alternator output is in the medium rpm range. Have your alternator tested by any auto store able to test it in the vehicle. You should examine both battery cables and their connections for corrosion, dried battery deposits, etc, that can interfere with alternator output. If original, the starter may be announcing its demise so check main power first (battery, cables, their connections and alt output.